# test xml node with c#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm having a problem to check if the element with some attributes exists. I will explain.. I have the following code

```
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(member.getProperty(itemlist).Value.ToString());
xDocument.Root.Add(new XElement(
    "Item",
    new XAttribute("Text", texts),
    new XAttribute("Value", values)));
member.getProperty(itemlist).Value = xDocument.ToString();
member.Save();
```

Well all I need you guys to understand is that simple - I  convert something into my `XDocument` (witch is a xml) and I simple add a new item on it with some attributes. But now there is my issue. I want to do this : If that item with that attributes exists **DELETE** , if not **ADD** . How can I do this test? Thanks anyway all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this :

```
var existingItem = 
        xDocument.Root
                 .Elements("Item")
                 .FirstOrDefault(o => 
                                      (string)o.Attribute("Text") == texts 
                                        && 
                                      (string)o.Attribute("Value") == values
                                 );
if(existingItem != null)
{
    //DELETE !!!
}
else
{
    //ADD !!!
}
```

Comment: Thats it man, this is the verification that i needed ! Thank you sir :D

Comment: @hard07 this is working 100% but on the add, he duplicates the item any idea why ?

Comment: At the moment, No idea. It should work just fine as far as I can see. Consider to open new question if you can't find the solution, post your codes for the **ADD** part there..